# How to dynamically retrieve a constant in java?

Tags: java, constants

I have several interfaces all with the same constants - ID and ROOT. I also have a method into which I pass an object that will be an implementation of one of these interfaces.

How can I dynamically retrieve the value of the constant depending on the class passed in - i.e. I want to do something like the following:

```
public void indexRootNode(Node node, Class rootNodeClass)
{
    indexService.index(node, rootNodeClass.getConstant('ID'), 
        rootNodeClass.getConstant('ROOT'));
}
```

In PHP this is easy, but is this possible in Java? I've seen this problem solved using accessors on the constant, but I want to retrieve the constant directly. Annotations won't help me here either.

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this question about storing constants in interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372991/should-a-collection-of-constants-be-placed-in-a-class-or-interface Most people agree, that an interface is not a good entity to store constants.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that. The interfaces I've created aren't collections of constants. I could thought about adding accessor methods to the interface, but for brevity I think in this case it's simpler to add constants to the interface.

Comment: @Andreas, the typical reason was to avoid having to type the Class.CONSTANT, but just be able to use CONSTANT.  This has gone away with static imports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) (also see corresponding [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)).

```
public void indexRootNode(Node node, Class rootNodeClass)
{
    Field idField = rootNodeClass.getField("ID");
    Object idValue = idField.get(null);
    Field rootField = rootNodeClass.getField("ROOT");
    Object rootValue = rootField.get(null);

    indexService.index(node, idValue, rootValue);
}
```

Maybe you may additionaly have to cast the values to the corresponding type.

Comment: you have a typo. Your "Field roorField" should be "rootField".

Answer (score 0):

Please read chapter 19 [use interfaces only to define types](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA98&ots=yXJnMfw3TX&dq=%22use%20interfaces%20only%20to%20define%20types%22&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q=%22use%20interfaces%20only%20to%20define%20types%22&f=false) from Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/url?client=ca-print-pearson-addison_wesley_pro&format=googleprint&num=0&channel=BTB-ca-print-pearson-addison_wesley_pro+BTB-ISBN:0321356683&q=http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683&usg=AFQjCNE5BjN9BaNo2A6ftJk0BwRERxbqFw&source=gbs_buy_s&cad=0) (in fact, please read the entire book)

Constants do not belong in an interface!!! Constants should be tied to implementing classes, not interfaces.

Either use non-constant methods:

```
// the implementing classes can define these values
// and internally use constants if they wish to
public interface BaseInterface{
    String id(); // or getId()
    String root(); // or getRoot()
}

public interface MyInterface1 extends BaseInterface{
    void myMethodA();
}

public interface MyInterface2 extends BaseInterface{
    void myMethodB();
}
```

or use an enum to tie things together:

```
public enum Helper{

    ITEM1(MyInterface1.class, "foo", "bar"),
    ITEM2(MyInterface2.class, "foo2", "baz"),
    ;

    public static String getId(final Class<? extends BaseInterface> clazz){
        return fromInterfaceClass(clazz).getId();

    }

    public static String getRoot(final Class<? extends BaseInterface> clazz){
        return fromInterfaceClass(clazz).getRoot();
    }

    private static Helper fromInterfaceClass(final Class<? extends BaseInterface> clazz){
        Helper result = null;
        for(final Helper candidate : values()){
            if(candidate.clazz.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
                result = candidate;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private final Class<? extends BaseInterface> clazz;

    private final String root;

    private final String id;

    private Helper(final Class<? extends BaseInterface> clazz,
        final String root,
        final String id){
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.root = root;
        this.id = id;

    };

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getRoot(){
        return this.root;
    }

}

// use it like this
String root = Helper.fromInterfaceClass(MyInterface1.class).getRoot();
```