# Java: Can interfaces contain constant variables defined in them?

Tags: java, interface, constants

Can I can create `public static final` variables in an interface? Can I keep some common constant values defined in these files?

Comment: Isn't this something that is trivial to simply *try*? You do have a working compiler, right?

Comment: I am sorry, I must rephrase. I have tried and it works. But I rather wanted to know if this is a good practice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a collection of constants be placed in a class or interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372991/should-a-collection-of-constants-be-placed-in-a-class-or-interface)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
public interface Constants
{
    public static final int ZERO = 0;
}
```

However, it's *generally* reckoned not to be a good idea these days. It's not so bad if the interface has a real purpose *as well*, and the constants are likely to be used by most of the implementations... but introducing an interface *just* to make it easier to get to constants is an abuse of the purpose of interfaces, really. (And that's what used to happen a lot.)

Comment: So then what is the solution? Define another class simply to define these constants?

Comment: @kiki: It depends on the situation. Sometimes enums work well instead of constants. Sometimes having them in a natural existing interface is as clean as anything else. Sometimes just keep them with the class that relates to them most strongly. Sometimes create a new class.

Comment: If you are implementing the interface only to avoid prefixing them with the interface name that is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can keep constants in interfaces. BTW, it's considered to be not very good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, `public` constants can be used declared inside interfaces. One thing, however, if your interface is just going to be placeholders for constants, use `enum` instead