# Is there any other type of static variable in Java than a static class variable?

Tags: java

In Java, can a static variable be anything other than a static *class* variable?  It seems the qualifier *class* is not strictly necessary when referring to static variables, other than to be super clear.

Comment: Yes, static variables are only associated with the class in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one kind of field that can be static and isn't associated with a class: [interface constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012124/java-can-interfaces-contain-constant-variables-defined-in-them), which are both static and final (and therefore not exactly a "variable", since they don't vary).

You can use them even without initializing an implementation of the interface, so they're not necessarily associated with a class at all. I believe they're [initialized when the interface is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722847/static-initialization-in-interface).

Answer (score 3):

From the Java Language Specification, on [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

> A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when
>   the class is initialized (§12.4).

They're one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are class variables, in that they all live within the context of a class, but you need to be careful in that you can have a static int, or a static string, etc, as well as a static class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields are always associated with a class, but you don't need to write the class name if you are referencing the field from the same class.