# Best Practice to define constant - inside class or inside interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, constants

I have a class which has only constant. Code snippets is :

```
public class CommonConstant
{

    public static final String  DAY                 = "DAY";
    public static final String  WEEK                = "WEEK";
    public static final String  MONTH               = "MONTH";
    public static final String  YEAR                = "YEAR";
    public static final String  ACCEPTED            = "accepted";
    public static final String  REJECTED            = "rejected";
    public static final String  ADDED               = "added";
    public static final String  MODIFIED            = "modified";

}
```

Is it good practice to specify constants in class file or it should be in an interface ?
What is good practice ?

Comment: Probably in enum!

Comment: Have a look at this question, I think it's exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372991/should-a-collection-of-constants-be-placed-in-a-class-or-interface

Comment: An Interface defines required behavior for arbitrary classes -- if the constants relate to the required Interface behavior, put the constants there!

Answer (score 4):

Since constants concerns implementation you should put them into a class with private constructor or, alternatively, an enum. Joshua Bloch in Effective Java 2nd edition discourage the use of "constant interfaces".

Bloch say that interfaces should be used only to define types and that when a class implements an interface this one serves as a type to refer to the instance -- it is inappropriate to use an interface for any other purpose. As said before, constants are implementation

and more concerning constant interfaces

> if in a future release the class is modified so that it no longer needs
>   to use the constants, it still must implement the interface to ensure
>   binary compatibility. If a nonfinal class implements a constant
>   interface, all of its subclasses will have their namespaces polluted
>   by the constants in the interface

BlocHquoted :)

HTH, Carlo

Comment: as you references effective java, it would be useful to point to the item that discourages the use of interfaces

Comment: Bloch discouraged it because...

Answer (score 4):

`What is a good practice`

This is actually a good practice

```
public enum EnumTest {
    DAY("DAY"), WEEK("WEEK"), MONTH("MONTH"), YEAR("YEAR");

    private String value;

    private EnumTest(String s) {
        value = s;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then in somewhere else

```
System.out.println(EnumTest.DAY.getValue()); // give you the value
```

or

```
for(EnumTest e :EnumTest.values()){ //values return an array of enum values
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: modifier private is redundant for enum constructor