# why enum has constructor when interface cant have one?

Tags: java, enums, constructor, interface

It is known that Interface doesn't need constructor because all the data members of interface are public,static and final. Similarly enum also has all its constants as public static and final then how come it needs/had a constructor?

Comment: The members of an enum can have arbitrary data members that need arbitrary initialization.

Comment: There are no direct instances of an `interface` (only instances of classes implementing that interface). But there *are* instances of `enum` (all enum values are instances of their respective enum type).

Comment: Related: [interface vs abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class) and [interfaces vs enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528561/interfaces-vs-enums)

Comment: Checkout this link for clarification:  http://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/sp17/classes/14-interfaces/

Answer (score 5):

An interface cannot be instantiated, an enum can (and in fact will be, as each of its members is an instance of the enum itself).