# C# const associated with an interface for a WCF service definition

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, constants

I am writing a WCF service and have a default `Fault` implementation that I am handling with an `IErrorHandler.ProvideFault`:

```
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        log.Error("ProvideFault called. Converting Exception to AdministrationFault....");

        var defaultFault = new FaultException<AdministrationFault>(
            new DefaultFault { Reason = error.Message }, error.Message);

        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version,
            defaultFault.CreateMessageFault(),
            DEFAULT_FAULT_ACTION);
    }
```

The const you see `DEFAULT_FAULT_ACTION` needs to have the same value as the `FaultContractAttribute` of my service.  Given that my service is defined in an interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/service/IFooService")]
public interface IFooService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DefaultFault),
        Action = "http://example.com/service/IFooService/fault/DefaultFault")]
    void AddUser(UserInfo userInfo, string password);
}
```

I cannot create `const` variables to store the namespace/action values.  So for now I am forced to create a class to store the constants:

```
public class StupidHackyConstClass {
    public const string NAMESPACE = "http://exampl.com/service/IFooService";
    public const string DEFAULT_FAULT_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "/fault/DefaultFault"
}
```

So that i can refactor the interface attributes and the error handler implementation to use common values.  I know a class for consts is a *terrible* anti-pattern, but it seems i am backed into a hole here...  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get why a static class for constants only is anti-pattern. I think your code is just fine. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263954/is-global-constants-an-anti-pattern

Comment: @thuan, thanks, possible i just inaccurately remembered the Effective Java _dont use interfaces just to declare constants_...